# How to get data from mongoose model and store with variable like mvc using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, data-manipulation

Here below code is sample MVC framework code in PHP. I need same process as like in node.js with mongoose also.

I'm using Node.js, MongoDB, REST API development.

*controller file:*

```
<?php
class Myclass {
 public function store_users() {
   //get the data from model file
   $country = $this->country->get_country_details($country_id);
  //After getting data do business logic
 }
}
```

*model file*

```
<?php
class Mymodel {
 public function get_country_details($cid) {
  $details = $this->db->table('country')->where('country_id',$id);
  return $details;
 }
}
```

In node.js need to use as like MVC PHP process. Kindly suggest on this.

Comment: Use **restify** , **mongoose**, jwt with **restify-jwt** to create an app. Search in google. You will find lot many blogs showing implementation. There it will be properly mentioned about mongoose model and restapi

Comment: @Priya, Already developed the API's based on blogs examples based on google search. In node.js separated the models,controllers,routes already. So here I need to get the data from model file using mongoose query method(every time need to write a query) always. So I need to use model function to get the data with all controllers, so need to solution for this.

Comment: There is no method like `mongoose query method`. But always you can use mongoose predefined methods like `find`, `findOne`, `exec`, `distinct`, `aggregate`, `findById`, `count` etc. ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have user schema in mongoose which should act as model

```
// userModel.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  dob: { type: Date },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true},
  active: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true}
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});

var userSchema = mongoose.model('users', user);
module.exports = userSchema;
```

```
// userController.js
var User = require('./userModel');

exports.getUserByEmail = function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.param.email;
    User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           next.ifError(err);
       }
       res.send({
           status: true,
           data: data
       });
       return next();
    });
};
```

Ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing can I use this public function anywhere within file right

Comment: Sorry no public. you can directly export the method or create an object out of it and export. like `var user = { getUserByEmail: getUserByEmail}; module.exports = user;` Public functions are nothing but exposed scope variables. private which cannot be exposed. Learn the use of `exports` in nodejs

Comment: This is not totally related to the question, but why is it that controllers finding the user with the email (User.findOne) isn't that model's job? Like, models interact with database right?